# Posting Photos and Other Attachments in a BuddyPress Forum?

Tags: buddypress, forum

I recently built a WordPress site based and am using BuddyPress for some interactive community functionality.  Members are using the forums built into BuddyPress, but are looking for a way to attach or embed pictures in their posts.  Is there any way to extend the BuddyPress forums to allow this, or are there existing plugins that allow this?  Or, is there a better forum that can be integrated into WordPress?

Comment: check that http://buddypress.org/community/groups/bp-album/ it might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And, since I can't (yet) post multiple links, here's two more answers in short succession.

For attachments, there's:

http://buddypress.org/community/groups/forum-attachments-for-buddypress/

Answer (score 1):

I've just added BuddyPress to a clean WordPress 3.0.1 install to try and find a suitable plugin, and I could simply embed images by using standard HTML tags:

`<img src="YOUR_IMG" />`, where `YOUR_IMG` is the URL of your image, embeds an image inline into a post.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Group Documents plugin for BuddyPress that lets you upload files to a group, also. Both that and the Forum Attachments plugin work with WP 3.0

Answer (score -1):

Always check the BuddyPress plugins listing for these sorts of questions *first*, i.e. http://buddypress.org/extend/plugins/